# How to detect request come from what device using PHP?

Tags: php, ios

I want to know a request which be sent to my PHP Webserver come from what device (iOS App, Web Browser...) and indentify of this device. Anybody can tell me to do it :) Thanks :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Browser_Detection_and_Cross_Browser_Support#Recommendations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's called the useragent. Check the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] variable on your requests and parse them.

Comment: If paser this useragent, can i get indentify of this device which send request?

Comment: You will not be able to get the UDID, if that's what you mean. Only what the device model that's on your page.

Comment: @Raphael Caixeta: Is there any way help me to get UDID of device which send request?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot UserAgentParsers around.

You can try many of them with this package https://github.com/ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser